# Cluster ELK + Kibana + Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the follow cenario: 1 node master, 2 data nodes and 1 client node (kibana+logstash) and a few questions.
Regarding the elasticsearch.yml configuration, should I need to configure an initial list of nodes that will be contacted to discover and form the cluster?

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["master-01", "datanode-01", "datanode-02"]

Regarding the logstash.conf file what IP do I put in Logstash's output's elasticsearch configuration? master-01 ip address?

```
output {
  elasticsearch { ? }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Logstash configuration needs to contact a data node or client node, but never a master node, whose only job is to coordinate the cluster, but not route search or index requests.

So a possible configuration could be the one below. Use the default HTTP port 9200 or whatever HTTP port you have configured (but not the TCP port):

```
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["datanode-01:9200", "datanode-02:9200"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Any node can be put in logstash configuration. As per elasticsearch documentation, Master node is also a data node only just that it has additional functionality of handling cluster.

Comment: If your master node is only a master node, then don't put it in the list, if it is master+data, then it's ok.